# How do I check if a user has a role in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make a command only accessible to people with an admin role, but all attempts I've made to check for it have not worked. I am using discord.py in the pyCharm editor. All help would be appreciated, I am a beginner.

```
if message.content.startswith('!gen'):
    import random
    num = random.randint(1, 100)
    if num < 50:
        await message.channel.send(str(num)+' was generated, so you get x.')
    if num > 50:
        await message.channel.send(str(num)+' was generated, so you get y.')
```

Comment: Have you tried using [commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/index.html?highlight=commands), they have easy checks you could add to restrict usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can simply check their permissions to see if they're an admin

```py
if member.guild_permissions.administrator:
   #member is an admin
```

### References:

- [guild_permissions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member.permissions_in)
- [Permissions.adminstrator](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Permissions.administrator)

Comment: While this is a correct answer, this method is fairly old and not used very often nowadays. A better way would be to use a command check (https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#checks).

Comment: I already recommended using that in the comments, this answers their question. using commands would mean rewriting their entire bot, which really doesn't answer their question

Comment: Ah, that makes much more sense.